# Find possible areas of triangle given radius of circumscribed circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, triangles

Question: **In triangle ABC, AB=4, AC=5, and the radius R of the circumscribed circle is equal to √7. Find all possible values of the area of triangle ABC.**

Through using the sine rule, i found the angle of B to be approximately $70.89339$, the angle of C to be approximately $49.10661$ and the angle of A to be $60$. Using the cosine law, I found the missing side length BC to be $√21$. Using Heron's law, I then found the area to be $5√3$.

However, this question requires more than one area. I am confused as to how to obtain the second area?

Answer (score 1):

$AB$ and $AC$ are two chords of a circle of radius $\sqrt7$. Picture this circle together with its diameter through $A$. The two chords can either be on the same side or opposite sides of this radius. You’ve computed the area of the resulting triangle for only one of these cases.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the sine rule cannot tell the difference between $\theta$ and $180-\theta$. Hence you have to check for the possibility of having an obtuse angle. If the angle at $B$ is $\approx 180-71 = 109$ it still leaves room for the angle at $C$ to be $\approx 50$. This will give a different area.

You should also check what happens when you replace $\approx 50$ by $\approx 180-50$.

Answer (score -1):

[image]You're right, there is only one possible answer. 
Since $M$ is the circumcenter of $\triangle ABC $, $MD $ is the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{AB} $. Applying the sine law in $\triangle ABC $ then gives $$|\measuredangle AMD|=\arcsin (\frac {2}{\sqrt {7}}). $$
Analogously, we obtain $$|\measuredangle EMD|=\arcsin (\frac {2.5}{\sqrt {7}}). $$
Overall this leads to $|\measuredangle EMD|= \frac {2\pi}{3} $ and therefore we get $|\measuredangle BAC|=|\measuredangle DAE|=\frac {\pi}{3 } $.
Hence, the area of our triangle comes out to be $\frac {1}{2} \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot \sin (\frac {\pi}{3 }) =5\sqrt {3}$, which is exactly your result.

Comment: There is another possibility: the point $C$ can be on the same side of the diameter through $A$ and $B$ instead of on the opposite side as you’ve drawn it.

Comment: @amd This cannot be the case since BAC would be acute then but also be equal to $arcsin (\frac {2}{\sqrt{7}})-arcsin (\frac {2.5}{\sqrt{7}})$. But this is roundabout $-22$ degrees or about $158$ degrees which cannot be right in both cases. Hence, what I've drawn is the only case that can occur.

Comment: Draw a circle of radius $5$ centered at $A$. It intersects the circle that you’ve drawn at two points, both of which are perfectly valid choices for $C$. Or, simply reflect the point $C$ that you’ve drawn in the diameter through $A$ to see that there’s another possible triangle. Whoever put together the problem that the OP is trying to solve certainly believed that there’s more than one non-congruent possibility for the inscribed triangle.